# How to cut a string after a specific character?

Tags: c, string

I've been recently asked to determine something's coordinates out of a DMEA code using c. An example of code is:

> $GPGGA,181908.00,3404.7041778,N,07044.3966270,W,4,13,1.00,495.144,M,29.200,M,0.10,0000*40.

I need to cut this in parts after every comma. Any one know how to do it wtih C?

Comment: You can use the strtok function in c. For more reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Comment: "Cut in parts"? What output do you want? Fifteen different files? Or terms 2-5 in one line separated by spaces? Or something else?

Comment: really, people dont know this kind of thing? How do they expect to be able to write any C code at all. Like a question yesterday "How can I add a character at the start of a string?". Really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your record format is fixed, it's convenient to use *scanf routines to read the records. It will also make necessary conversions into numeric types. Here is an example for your string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Rec {
    char var [128];
    float x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8;
    int i1, i2, i3;
    char c1, c2, c3, c4;
} Rec; // Rename fields to something meaningful

int read_rec(Rec *o, const char *s)
{
    int n = sscanf(s,
        "%[^,],%f,%f,%c,%f,%c,%d,%d,%f,%f,%c,%f,%c,%f,%d*%f",
      &o->var, &o->x1, &o->x2, &o->c1, &o->x3, &o->c2, &o->i1, &o->i2, &o->x4,
      &o->x5, &o->c3, &o->x6, &o->c4, &o->x7, &o->i3, &o->x8);
    if (n != 16 /* num of fields */) {
        printf ("Rec struct reading failed after %d field(s) read: %s\n",
        n, s);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

void print_rec(const Rec *r, FILE *of)
{
    fprintf(of,
        "%s,%f,%f,%c,%f,%c,%d,%d,%f,%f,%c,%f,%c,%f,%d*%f",
      r->var, r->x1, r->x2, r->c1, r->x3, r->c2, r->i1, r->i2, r->x4,
      r->x5, r->c3, r->x6, r->c4, r->x7, r->i3, r->x8);
}

int main() {
    const char *desc = "$GPGGA,181908.00,3404.7041778,N,07044.3966270,W,4,13,1.00,495.144,M,29.200,M,0.10,0000*40.";
    struct Rec rec;
    if (read_rec(&rec, desc))
        print_rec(&rec, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```